# Problem with Texture Mapping (Brick Texture works only on on surface and not on that ones who are normal to it)

Tags: materials, uv, shaders

I want to make a headphone with a fabrik patern. But when I want to use the Brick Texture with a UV map, I get the pattern only on one the sides and not on top and at the bottom of the model. What I'm doing wrong? (Every advice is welcome, also tips for my shader).

[image: My setup]

Comment: Have you tried using a second UV map for the brick texture, maybe the default reset position of all faces overlayed? I also wonder if this is a matter of checking the face normals?

Comment: face normals arent, becouse at the inside it's the same that on top it's grey and on the side is the pattern

Comment: I only used one UV map so far for the fabric pattern, when I move the Verts in the UV's it's stil the same situation. So the UV Map is only to control the bricktexture.

Comment: If I skip the displayement node, I get the result I want to have.